# Getting the value of page type form

Tags: kentico

[image]

I'm trying to add a new field named "AlternateLink" to our news page types.
Currently the "Read More" button goes to the full article page with the following:

```
<a href="<%# GetDocumentUrl() %>" class="button pull-right">Read More</a>
```

I've updated it to:

```
<a href="<%# IfEmpty(Eval("AlternateLink",true), GetDocumentUrl(), Eval("AlternateLink",true)) %>" class="button pull-right">Read More</a>
```

but even with a link in the Alternate Link field (see attached image), it always links to the full article page instead of the alternate link.

I tried the same IfEmpty statement with other existing field names such as "NewsTitle" or "NewsImage" and those seem to work so the issue seems to be "AlternateLink" field name.

I created a field with the ID of "AlternateLink" as a text box. Am I missing another step to make it capture the value?

EDIT: AlternateLink is the only new thing I'm adding. All of the existing values (NewsTeaser, NewsTitle, NewsSummary, etc.) all work. Full code:

```
  <div class="blog-post col-md-12 clearfix">
  <cms:Media ID="mTeaser" runat="server" Url='<%# Eval("NewsTeaser") %>' Class="img-responsive" />
  <h2 class="blog-title"><%# Eval("NewsTitle",true) %></h2>
  <div class="post-info">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><%# GetDateTime("NewsReleaseDate", "MMMM dd, yyyy") %>
  </div>
  <p><%# Eval("NewsSummary") %></p>
  <a href="<%# IfEmpty(Eval("AlternateLink",true), GetDocumentUrl(), Eval("AlternateLink",true)) %>" class="button pull-right">Read More</a>
  <span class="hr col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked columns field of the web part, that shows news on the page? Make sure AlternateLink column is also listed there.

Comment: aha that was it. i'm still getting familiar with kentico so wasn't sure what to look for. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Eval` for Text/XML transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested using just `<%#Eval("AlternateLink",true)%>` to see what it returns?

Looks like your code is `{%Eval("AlternateLink",true)%}` when it should be `{%AlternateLink%}`.  `<%#%>` is for ASPX Transformations. `{%%}` is for Text/XML transformations, which it looks like you are using.

Comment: I believe I need ASPX. I just tried it in Text/XML now and it just gave errors. I tried just `code`(<%#Eval("AlternateLink",true)%> ) and it's returning blank `code`(<a href="" class="button pull-right">Read More</a>)

Comment: did the coding wrong (new to SO) but yeah, `<%#Eval("AlternateLink",true)%>` return `<a href="" class="button pull-right">Read More</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this.

```
<a href="<%# ( (Eval("AlternateLink")==null || Eval("AlternateLink").ToString()=="") ?  GetDocumentUrl() : Eval("AlternateLink",true))%>" class="button pull-right">Read More</a>
```